# New deployment is going into ImagePullBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, docker-image

I have installed minikube in my local machine and have created a deployment from a yaml file with `imagePullPolicy: Always`.

On runnning, minikube kubectl -- get pods,the status of the pods is `imagePullPolicy: ImagePullBackOff`.
and on running

```
 minikube kubectl  -- describe pod podname
```

I am getting the following results:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----    ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Normal  Pulling  5m39s (x103 over 26h)  kubelet  Pulling image "deploy1:1.14.2"
  Normal  BackOff  44s (x2244 over 26h)   kubelet  Back-off pulling image "deploy1:1.14.2"
```

Please suggest how to make the deployment running. I have gone through the [link](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/kubectl-unable-to-deploy-the-pod-in-the-cluster/) but I could not find the service.xml file of the pod. Where is it in the Kubernetes in the local system/?

Comment: Where is this image located - deploy1:1.14? Are you able to manually pull the file using docker pull deploy1:1.14. From what I can see, you are using a private registry and you will have to create the imagePullSecret and use it in your Deployment.

Answer (score 3):

It means either you are trying to pull a image from a private repo or you don't have connectivity to outside. You can test this, but running command `kubectl run <pod_name> --image=nginx`. If this works then it means you are trying to pull a image from a repo which requires auth.